# compare schema ignoring nullable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to compare the schema of 2 dataframes. 
Basically, the columns and the types are the same, but the "nullable" can be different:

Dataframe A

```
StructType(List(
StructField(ClientId,StringType,True),
StructField(PublicId,StringType,True),
StructField(ExternalIds,ArrayType(StructType(List(
    StructField(AppId,StringType,True),
    StructField(ExtId,StringType,True),
)),True),True),
....
```

Dataframe B

```
StructType(List(
StructField(ClientId,StringType,True),
StructField(PublicId,StringType,False),
StructField(ExternalIds,ArrayType(StructType(List(
    StructField(AppId,StringType,True),
    StructField(ExtId,StringType,False),
)),True),True),
....
```

When I do `df_A.schema == df_B.schema`, result if `False` obviously.
But I would like to ignore the "nullable" parameter, whether it is false or true, if the structure is the same, it should return `True`.

Is it possible ?

Comment: replace all false to true and then compare

Comment: A and B are generated from 2 different processes. I cannot change them. I just want to compare them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your example of the following two DataFrame schemas:

```python
df_A.printSchema()
#root
# |-- ClientId: string (nullable = true)
# |-- PublicId: string (nullable = true)
# |-- PartyType: string (nullable = true)

df_B.printSchema()
#root
# |-- ClientId: string (nullable = true)
# |-- PublicId: string (nullable = true)
# |-- PartyType: string (nullable = false)
```

and assuming that the fields are in the same order, you can access the `name` and `dataType` of each of the fields in the schemas and zip them to compare:

```python
print(
    all(
        (a.name, a.dataType) == (b.name, b.dataType) 
        for a,b in zip(df_A.schema, df_B.schema)
    )
)
#True
```

If they are not in the same order, you can compare the sorted fields:

```python
print(
    all(
        (a.name, a.dataType) == (b.name, b.dataType) 
        for a,b in zip(
            sorted(df_A.schema, key=lambda x: (x.name, x.dataType)), 
            sorted(df_B.schema, key=lambda x: (x.name, x.dataType))
        )
    )
)
#True
```

If it's possible that the two DataFrames could have differing number of columns, you could first compare the schema lengths as a short circuiting check- if this fails, don't bother iterating through the fields:

```python
print(len(df_A.schema) == len(df_B.schema))
#True
```

Answer (score 1):

When using pytest I prefer using sets because, pytest will point out the difference if there is any.

```py
assert {(c.name, c.dataType) for c in df_A.schema} == {(c.name, c.dataType) for c in df_B.schema}
```